# Exporting data from BI to Azure

Tags: azure, powerbi, dax, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to export data from Power Bi into Azure. I have set up a logic app to get this done but, I'm trying to figure out if I can filter the data by previous month by adding a filter function in the required query statement. I have been trying to figure this out for a while but came up with nothing. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can this be done?

Yes.  You just need to build an appropriate DAX query.  Here's a couple of simple samples:

This query returns all the rows with OrderDate in the current month:

```
evaluate
(
     filter(
          'FactInternetSales',
          'FactInternetSales'[OrderDate] >= date(year(now()),month(now()),1)
        )
)
```

This query returns one full month of data ending today:

```
evaluate
(
     filter(
          'FactInternetSales',
          'FactInternetSales'[OrderDate] >= edate(now(),-1)
        )
)
```